# Comment lines in orgmode

Tags: emacs, comments, org-mode

Consult org document with the comments lines:

[The Org Manual: Comment lines](https://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html)

> #### 12.6 Comment lines
>
> Lines starting with zero or more whitespace characters followed by one ‘#’ and a whitespace are treated as comments and, as such, are not exported.
>
> Likewise, regions surrounded by `#+BEGIN_COMMENT` ... `#+END_COMMENT` are not exported.
>
> Finally, a ‘COMMENT’ keyword at the beginning of an entry, but after any other keyword or priority cookie, comments out the entire subtree. In this case, the subtree is not exported and no code block within it is executed either[129](https://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html#FOOT129). The command below helps changing the comment status of a headline.
>
> <kbd>C-c ;</kbd>
>
> Toggle the ‘COMMENT’ keyword at the beginning of an entry.

`#+BEGIN_COMMENT  …  #+END_COMMENT` works correctly.

[image: Code block showing comment]

However,

> Lines starting with zero or more whitespace characters followed by one ‘#’ and a whitespace are treated as comments and, as such, are not exported.

[image: Another code block]

Do I misunderstand that statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You read it well: working comment syntax are

```
#+BEGIN_COMMENT
this is a comment
#+END_COMMENT
```

or

```
# this is a comment (needs at least one first whitespace after #)
```

However

```
#this is not a comment (it is exported as "#this is not a comment")
```